# Configuring Cypress.env() variable to an imported module file

Tags: javascript, import, module, environment-variables, cypress

I'm trying to set & config a new `env` variable in [Cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/). In the file `cypress/plugins/index.js`, I have imported another file like so:

```
const { getBranch } = require('path/to/file/goes/here/getBranch');
```

Then, I'm trying to set the new `env` variable like so:

```
// cypress/plugins/index.js

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  terminalReport.installPlugin(on);

  const configuration = config;
  configuration.env.injectMainBranchId = getBranch('develop');

  // more code below...
```

However, this is not working. However, if I hardcode the value it does work:

```
configuration.env.injectMainBranchId = 'develop';
```

You see the result in the screenshot below:
[image]

This is the dummy content of `getBranch` module:

```
const getBranch = branch => {
  return branch;
};

module.export = { getBranch };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typo in `module.exports = { getBranch };`

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in getBranch:

```
const getBranch = branch => {
  return branch;
};

module.export = { getBranch };
```

`export` should be changed to `exports`